# What is dyadic in linear algebra?

Tags: vectors

Suppose a vector $\large\vec{a}$. It can be written as:

$$\large\sum_i \vec{e_i}\,\vec{e_i}\cdot \vec{a}=\vec{1}\cdot\vec{a}$$

where $\large\vec{e_i}$ are unit basis vectors.

I can't figue out what is $\large\vec{1}$ (called *dyadic*) and how to obtain it from $\large\vec{e_i}\vec{e_i}$. Reading Wikipedia gave no undestanding.

Would you help me?

Comment: A *dyad* is a matrix of the form ${\bf a}{\bf b}^T=(a_ib_j)_{i,j}$, which is also called the dyadic product of vectors ${\bf a}$ and ${\bf b}$.

Comment: @Berci So is a multiplication from "all to all" components? I supposed **ab** $^T$ was not allowed since number of columns of a is different from *b* rows number

Comment: It's not allowed. But if $\bf a$ is an $n$ dimensional column vector, ${\bf b}^T$ is an $m$ dim. row vector, then their matrix product is defined and is $n\times m$.

Comment: Btw, I can't parse your formula with $e_i$'s..

Comment: @Berci what do you mean with: then their matrix product is defined and is $n×m$

Comment: I mean $\pmatrix{a_1\\ \vdots\\ a_n} \pmatrix{b_1&\dots&b_m}$.

Comment: @Berci yes, i understand that. But then you can multiply them? despite the issue with columns and rows?

Comment: What issue? One equals to one. You can multiply them. The dyads are of this form, i.e. they have rank $\le 1$.

Comment: @Berci I didn't understand but thanks.

Comment: You can mulitply an $n\times 1$ matrix to an $1\times m$ matrix. Well, in your case $n=m$, and I guess, at least a transpose sign is missing..

Comment: @Berci oh you are right, Im sorry! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notation in the equation is misleading. We all agree that if $a$ and $b$ are column vectors, we can multiply them as $a^{\rm T} b$ and $ab^{\rm T}$, but certainly we can’t perform $ab$. On the other hand, I’m prone to believe $\vec e_i \cdot \vec a$ means $\vec e^{\rm T}_i \vec a$, the stantard inner product of vectors (which in this case, actually gives the $i$th entry of $\vec a$, $a_i$.) I would also add a parenthesis to the equation: $$\sum_i \vec e_i (\vec e_i \cdot \vec a) =\sum_i \vec e_i (\vec e^{\rm T}_i \vec a) =\sum_i (\vec e_i \vec e^{\rm T}_i) \vec a =\Big(\sum_i \vec e_i \vec e^{\rm T}_i\Big) \vec a = \text{Id } \vec a,$$ where Id is the identity matrix that has as many columns as $\vec a$ has entries. (By the way, $\vec 1$ usually denotes a vector with only ones and it shouln’t be there.)

Answer (score 1):

The dot product $$\vec{1}\cdot \vec{a} = \sum_i \vec{e_i}\vec a$$

What you have instead is:

$$\sum_i \vec{e_i}(\vec{e_i} \cdot \vec a)$$

Which is like the sum of the projections of $\vec a$ onto the basis.